# Magento - Issue with php code not running

Tags: magento

PHP code not running in /header.phtml
I have the following code in /app/design/frontend/default/gumball/template/page/html/header.phtml

```
<li class="my-cart">
<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/')?>" class="cartcount cartlink">

<? if(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsSummaryQty() > 0) { ?>
<?=__(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsSummaryQty())?> 
    <? } else { ?>
    0 
 <? } ?> Item(s)

  </a>
</li>
```

On the current server the Correct html being produced is

```
<li class="my-cart">
   <a href="http://www.gumball-machine.com/checkout/cart/" class="cartcount cartlink">
   0 Item(s)</a>
```

but on the other server that I am trying to move the current site to I get the following html

```
<li class="my-cart">
<a href="http://www.ecandymachine.com/checkout/cart/" class="cartcount cartlink">
<? if(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsSummaryQty() > 0) { ?>
<?=__(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsSummaryQty())?> 
<? } else { ?>
0 
<? } ?> Item(s)
  </a>
```

It seems that the php code is not running. What can I do to resolve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a magento issue. It's a server configuration "issue".
Most likely short tags are not enabled on you server. Change your code into this and it should work regardless of the short tags settings.

```
<li class="my-cart">
<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/')?>" class="cartcount cartlink">

<?php if(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsSummaryQty() > 0) { ?>
<?php echo __(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsSummaryQty())?> 
    <?php } else { ?>
    0 
 <?php } ?> Item(s)

  </a>
</li>
```

A bit off topic:
read more guidelines on [how to write magento code](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/8345/146). Your issue is listed in there also.